# "ulimit -r unlimited" in docker image. "cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted"

Tags: centos, docker, ulimit

I'm trying to set my real-time priority to unlimited on my CentOS 7 (CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)) image running in Docker.

I'm executing (as root):

```
ulimit -r unlimited
```

I'm receiving the following error:

```
bash: ulimit: real-time priority: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
```

I pulled the centos 7 container from https://hub.docker.com/_/centos.

When executing `ulimit -a`,  I'm met with

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 514022
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1048576
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) unlimited
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Is setting the real-time priority to something other than zero even feasible in the docker container?